# Is there a package for semantic refactoring

Tags: python, ide, refactoring

Is there a package that allows syntax aware refactoring in python or c++. For example, extracting a value as a parameter, into a function signature, extracting a block as a function (passing local values as parameters into the function signature).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python:

https://github.com/python-rope/ropemacs

https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy (also base on rope)

C++:

https://github.com/tuhdo/semantic-refactor

https://github.com/thoni56/c-xrefactory

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question years later: support for LSP via `eglot` takes care of most of my problems.